# xlab and ylab in barplot not being displayed

Tags: r, bar-chart

So I have specified some strings to both `xlab` and `ylab` in the `barplot` function but I they are not being displayed for some reason. Also, I have specified `beside=T` and the bars don't position side by side. Here's the code:

```
barplot(height=c(mean(d2$tconv[d2$NFUP==1]), mean(d2$tconv[d2$FUP==1])),
        col = c(2,3), names.arg=levels(d$progu1), 
        main="Tiempo de Conversión según si el usuario convertido ha acabado la 1era Unidad",
        ylim=c(0,max(mean(d2$tconv[d2$FUP==1]), mean(d2$tconv[d2$NFUP==1]))+10),
        xlab="Uso", ylab="Tiempo hasta Conversión", border=F, beside=T)
```

Here's the result. Zooming doesn't help:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I could not replicate the axes not showing up with sample data.

Comment: Beside = T will work if you compare different groups within "No Acaba la Unidad" and " Acaba la Unidad". For the xlab and ylab I don't know what is going wrong. Any chance you lose them because you do some kind of zooming? Your title seems to be cut as well.

Comment: Have you changed your margins with [par](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html)? The graph looks like it's smaller than it should be and it may have cut off the labels.

Comment: tip: use `"\n"` in the `character` string of `main` to split your title to multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand how beside = T works check this:

```
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)


barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)


barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts), beside=FALSE)


barplot(counts[2,], main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set wider margins. For example:

```
par(mar=c(4,4,4,4))
```

Current margins you can check by calling:

```
par()
```